# Why is my Systemd unit arkos-redis loaded, but inactive (dead)?

Tags: systemd

Here's what I have in my service file, `arkos-redis.service`:

```
GNU nano 2.4.2   File: /usr/lib/systemd/user/arkos-redis.service              

[Unit]
Description=Advanced key-value store

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/arkos/arkos-redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-cli shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But when boot I get the following status:

```
[vagrant@arkos-vagrant etc]$ systemctl --user status arkos-redis.service
��arkos-redis.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/arkos-redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your service file is in `/usr/lib/systemd/user`, it is treated as a user service, and is started by your own instance of `systemd` (run as `systemd --user`). This means, among other things, that the process is started under your user, not `root`, and is started for each user that logs in. Based on the reference to the config file in `/etc`, I would guess that only one instance of this process should be running at any given time, and that it should run as `root` (or some other system accout). If this process is supposed to start as `root`, move this file to `/usr/lib/systemd/system` (or better yet, `/etc/systemd/system`, since it's your own service file) and ignore the rest of this answer.

If your service file is supposed to start under your own user, then note that only the following targets are available in user mode:

```
   When systemd runs as a user instance, the following special units are available, which have
   similar definitions as their system counterparts: default.target, shutdown.target,
   sockets.target, timers.target, paths.target, bluetooth.target, printer.target,
   smartcard.target, sound.target.
```

Neither `multi-user.target` nor `network.target` are available, and so your service won't start automatically. If you want it to start, change `multi-user.target` to `default.target`, and get rid of `After=network.target`. Then, run `systemctl --user enable arkos-redis.service`.

Comment: My service is supposed to start under my own user.

Comment: See the remainder of my answer, which applies for user services. Note that this also means that the service won't start until _after_ you log in, and will stop when you log off. If you want it to always start, you can keep it as a system service and set `User=folatt` (replace with your Linux username).

Comment: It's not starting automatically with the current configuration, nor adding the User.

Comment: Thank you, what was missing was that I had to redo ```systemctl --user enable arkos-redis.service```, because the link has to be recreated.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that part. My bad.